# Gunicorn not able to kill an external process

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, gunicorn

Hello I have a web application written in Flask which is attached to a USB credit card swiper. The code for the swiper is written in java and my flask app is something like this

```
@app.route("/swipe")
def index():
    a = Popen(["sudo", "java", "sample"], shell=False)
    sts2 = os.waitpid(p.pid, 0)
    return "hello"


@app.route("/kill_swiper", methods=["POST"])
def index_2():
    try:
        pid = request.json
        pid = pid.get("pid")
        os.kill(int(pid), signal.SIGTERM)
        return Response(json.dumps({"status": True}), status=200, mimetype='application/json')

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        return Response(json.dumps({"status": False}),
                        status=417, mimetype='application/json')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.config['TEMPLATES_AUTO_RELOAD'] = True
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0")
```

Whenever the user clicks a button the swiper will be triggered redirecting him to a page where he can either swipe card or click cancel.

Coming to my problem, I am able to kill the swiper externally by running the command

`sudo kill <pid of swiper>`

But when I try to click the cancel button on the website, it is not getting killed. I am running the flask application behind **gunicorn** and I am using the following command to run gunicorn

```
sudo gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:5000 --workers 3 app:app
```

I tried giving threads as an option but it did not work. Can someone tell me where I am going wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated**

Using `sudo` creates two processes; a parent `sudo` process and a child that runs the actual command. Most signals (including SIGTERM) are supposed to be passed from parent `sudo` process to child, however, there are various scenarios in which it might not. Possibly this is happening. You need to make sure that you are killing the child process.

You should be able to circumvent the problem by running `gunicorn` directly as root and removing the `sudo`. However, from a security standpoint, it's best to avoid running server processes such as `gunicorn` as root. Does the java card reader really require it? If there are permission issues concerning the opening of the USB port, there are ways around this. Some ideas can be found here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/72437/how-to-grant-non-root-user-access-to-device-files

---

`os.kill()` is trying to kill a privileged process (started with `sudo`), but the flask process is not privileged. You should be seeing an error response.

Try `Popen(['sudo', 'kill', pid])` or similar.

If you are not getting an error response the server might be blocking on the `os.waitpid()` in the `/swipe` request so the `/kill_swiper` request is not processed until the card reader process terminates.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but everything is running as sudo. I have also tried your answer but no luck. I am able to get the PID and kill it with another flask process running in different port though. I have also tried running gunicorn like this `gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:5000 --workers 3 -u root -g root app:app`

Comment: Is there a better way other than `os.waitpid()`

Comment: You could use `p.wait()`, but that will be the same as `os.waitpid()`, although a little cleaner.

Comment: Thanks @mhawke, I will try that

Comment: Dude you are magical, finally I got it working. Thank you soo much